# Deta In-line Smart Switch

Tags: electrical, smart-switch

Just checking that I got this correct. I’m in Australia.

[image]

Comment: What do the instructions say?  I've searched the web for that product but it's not popping up.

Comment: I would guess that you have it correct - most things like inline tend to keep the same terminal orientation...

Comment: both brown wires appears to be on the wrong side of the screw ... the end of a wire should wrap around the screw in a clockwise direction

Comment: Thanks for the help! I consulted an electrician friend, he said wiring was good just a bit sloppy. I trimmed them up and it works!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add your results as an answer? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the DETA Smart Inline switch, in Australia, this above pictured wiring is correct, if not a bit messy, cleaned up the connections and it works perfectly.